# Display the selected variation Sku in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have this code in `functions.php` to output selected variation Sku in WooCommerce

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_sku', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_sku( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
$variation_data['price_html'] .= '<span class="sku">' . $variation_data['sku'] . '</span>';

    return $variation_data;
}
```

It currently displays before the *add to cart* button

How can I make it displays after the **product title**?

2) I put this code in .../woocommerce/single-product/title.php

```html
<div class="product_sku">
    
    <div class="nm-row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">

            <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>
            
                <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But it shows SKU for the 1st variation only. When I select another variation SKU doesn't change.

Comment: You need to deregister this from the `woocommerce_available_variation` filter and add it to the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` filter. If you look in the product templates from woocommerce you can see how their logic works

Comment: Adding to the woocommerce_single_product_summary filter does't help.